# 4-bit Decimal to Binary Converter using on-board BeagleBone Black LEDs

Tags: c++, linux, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to write a c++ program that converts a number between 1 and 15 to binary and displays the output via on-board BeagleBone Black LEDs.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
FILE *BINHandle = NULL;
const char *LED0="/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0/brightness";
const char *LED1="/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr1/brightness";
const char *LED2="/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr2/brightness";
const char *LED3="/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr3/bringtness";

int a, b, c;

cout << "Enter an number between 1 and 15" << endl;
cin >> a;
cout << a << " in binary is:" << endl;

for(b = 3; b >=0; b--){
c = a >> b;

if(c & 1){

if(b = 3){
BINHandle = fopen(LED3, "r+");
fwrite("1", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);
}
else{
BINHandle = fopen(LED3, "r+");
fwrite("0", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);
}

if(b = 2){
BINHandle = fopen(LED2, "r+");
fwrite("1", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);
}
else{
BINHandle = fopen(LED2, "r+");
fwrite("0", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);
}

if(b = 1){
BINHandle = fopen(LED1, "r+");
fwrite("1", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);
}
else{
BINHandle = fopen(LED1, "r+");
fwrite("0", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);
}

if(b = 0){
BINHandle = fopen(LED0, "r+");
fwrite("1", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);
}
else{
BINHandle = fopen(LED0, "r+");
fwrite("0", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);
}

}

}
usleep(2000000);


BINHandle = fopen(LED0, "r+");
fwrite("0", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);

BINHandle = fopen(LED1, "r+");
fwrite("0", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);

BINHandle = fopen(LED2, "r+");
fwrite("0", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);

BINHandle = fopen(LED3, "r+");
fwrite("0", sizeof(char), 1, BINHandle);
fclose(BINHandle);


}
```

Now I'm trying to access the leds individually whenever that bit is 1. I get no errors, but when I run the code and enter a number, when I should get an output I get "Segmentation fault"

Comment: If you wanted it to be easy to read your code, you *would* have it indented. :)

Comment: How does this line even compile? `const char *BIN = (LED3<<3)+(LED2<<2)+(LED1<<1)+LED0;`

Comment: @tangrs It doesn't. At least, not in clang; I can't speak for other compilers.

Comment: WTF? You cant concenate strings like that! Open each file individually! Why dont you do that via BASH script? Would be much less work

Answer (score 3):

```
const char *LED0="/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0/brightness";
const char *LED1="/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr1/brightness";
const char *LED2="/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr2/brightness";
const char *LED3="/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr3/bringtness";
const char *BIN = (LED3<<3)+(LED2<<2)+(LED1<<1)+LED0;
```

You can't combine strings together like that.

If you want to read from or write to multiple files, you'll need to open each one and read/write it individually.

Comment: Is there a way I can pass that job to the for loop?

Comment: @John I'm not sure what you mean by "that job".

Comment: Right now I am just dealing with a 4-bit converter so I can access each one individually, but in the case I had 16 leds accessed through files, is there a way to name them LED0, LED1, ...LED15 and have a loop for(i=15; i >=0; i--) and access and write to LEDi each pass

Comment: Use an array, or generate the filenames with `sprintf()` to a buffer.